HTML table: page breaks creating extra pages due to rowspan
A very large rowspan in one of the columns in my html table appears to be creating close to 60 blank pages on a page break between two sections.
I have a large html table with many many sections that I am creating from parsing a csv file in python, exporting to html, and then using BeautifulSoup to adjust and format that html. Everything was working fine until I tried to introduce page breaks after each section (sections in this example are each lowercase letter: i.e. 'b', 'e').
I believe the issue comes from the cell labeled "Long Rowspan". This column spans the entire length of the document and is necessary to be there. When I put a border on this cell, I can see that the border spans all these pages and that's why they are printing.
I don't understand why the rowspan is creating blank space. It doesn't have any tangible size. Does any know what I am doing wrong or how I can fix this? The extra pages occur between the first and second sections, and then every other section is completely fine and looks good.
I tried setting the rowspan to a different value, and although that did change the number of blank pages, it messes up the formatting of the entire document.
I tried setting the display to block but that also messed up the formatting and did not remove the blank pages.
Here is a code snippet of the sections.
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head><style type="text/css">@page { size: landscape; }</style></head><body>
<p><b>Fund:</b> Multiple</p>
<p><b>Run Date:</b> nan</p>
<table border="0" border-collapse="collapse" class="dataframe" style="border: 1px solid grey; font-size: 85%;" table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr style="text-align: center;">
<th style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: solid; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none;"></th>
<th style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: solid; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none;"></th>
<th style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: solid; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none;"></th>
<th style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: solid; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none;"></th>
<th style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: solid; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none;">Comparison</th>
<th style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: solid; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: solid; border-left-style: none;">Limit</th>
<th style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: solid; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none;">Value</th>
<th style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: solid; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none;">Cushion</th>
<th style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: solid; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none;">Result</th>
<th style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: solid; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none;">Numerator</th>
<th style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: solid; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none;">Denominator</th>
<th style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: solid; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none;">Info</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>

// here is where the rowspan begins
<th rowspan="1322" style="border: 1px solid red; border-bottom-style: solid; border-top-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; min-width: 1px; height: 18px" valign="top"><div style="width: 1.5em; white-space: nowrap; overflow: visible; padding-top: 3px;">Long rowspan</div></th>
<td style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: none; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none; height: 18px;"></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: none; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none; height: 18px;"></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: none; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none; height: 18px;"></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: none; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none; text-align: center; height: 18px;"></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: none; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: solid; border-left-style: none; height: 18px;"></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: none; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none; height: 18px; text-align: right; padding: 7px;"></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: none; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none; height: 18px;"></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: none; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none; height: 18px;"></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: none; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none; height: 18px;"></td>
</tr>

// ... lots of data in this section that looks like this
<td style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: solid; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none; text-align: right; padding: 7px 7px 7px 2px; white-space: nowrap;">59</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: solid; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none; text-align: center;"></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: solid; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: solid; border-left-style: none; text-align: right; padding: 7px 7px 7px 2px; white-space: nowrap;">0.286244</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: solid; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none; text-align: right; padding: 7px 7px 7px 2px; white-space: nowrap;">0.663459</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: solid; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none; text-align: right; padding: 7px 7px 7px 2px; white-space: nowrap;">0.302813</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: solid; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none;"></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: solid; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none; text-align: right; padding: 7px 7px 7px 2px; white-space: nowrap;">0.180261</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: solid; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none; text-align: right; padding: 7px 7px 7px 2px; white-space: nowrap;">0.994990</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: solid; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none;"></td>

// ... skipping to beginning of next section

// beginning of section 2 after the 60 page long page break
<tr style="display: block;">
<th rowspan="39" style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: none; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none; min-width: 1px; height: 18px" valign="top"><div style="page-break-before: always; width: 1.5em; white-space: nowrap; overflow: visible; padding-top: 3px;">e</div></th>
<td style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: none; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none; height: 18px;"></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: none; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none; height: 18px;"></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: none; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none; text-align: center; height: 18px;"></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: none; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: solid; border-left-style: none; height: 18px;"></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: none; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none; height: 18px; text-align: right; padding: 7px;"></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: none; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none; height: 18px;"></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: none; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none; height: 18px;"></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid grey; border-bottom-style: none; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none; height: 18px;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>

You'll notice on the first cell of section 2 I put page-break-before-always on the div. Without this line here, I don't get any extra pages.
This is what the pdf looks like:
page 1: Beginning of the file, looks good. I highlighted the border of the long rowspan cell so you can see how far it goes

page2: the end of the first section, where a page break is coming. However, you can see the border of the long rowspan row continues past this page

page3: one of the many empty pages between the first and second sections. The rowspan border continues through this blank space

page 4: the beginning of section 2. Although the formatting is off because I set display : block, Section 2 and every other section of the pdf behaves as expected.

I can't post the whole pdf because it is 160 pages long, but imagine 60 duplicates of page3 that I posted.
